# How to implement a phone number field mask in custom component?

Tags: jform, custom-component, form-fields-types, view, custom-field

How can I implement an input field mask for JForms in my component? Specifically I want a phone number mask something like (***)***-____. I only want users to enter digits and not have them enter parenthesis or dash. I also don't want to store the phone number with the parenthesis or dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own field type to display custom content in your field.

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

While creating your own field type, you may want to extend the existing form fields functionality. text field is one such option in your case:

https://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type

You can add client side validations using jQuery plugin like "jQuery validations"

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I've been using custom fields for drop-down lists and such. I assume from your answer that there is no built-in functionality to mask an input field for things such as phone numbers, dates, id numbers, etc.? I guess that means that I have to code it. Any idea where I can find open-source code I could use?

Comment: Yes, there is no built-in option to mask the input for phone numbers etc. You can use the code mentioned in the above documentation. It has pretty much full code which you need.